# windows could not retrieve information about the disk on this computer

Tags: disk

i am trying to install **wondows 10** on my new lenovo ideapad 330 AMD A4, for the first time (my laptop is without an operating system now), but i am getting this message error:

> **windows could not retrieve information about the disk on this computer**

how i can figure it out ??

Comment: You will not get help with that on this community - I think, this is for coders. However, search for that exact phrase on google.com (obviously) and call your most computer capable friend? :-).

Comment: Hope you find a solution. If all fails I usually try to install Linux instead. [**Linux Mint**](https://linuxmint.com/) is my poison of choice ([ISO download](https://linuxmint.com/download.php) - I just go "*Cinnamon*"). Quite acceptable for simple use and full of "auto-magic". LibreOffice, Chrome and FireFox. **Note that installing Linux without being an expert tends to wipe the whole drive**.